# What field contains the "created date" in a SharePoint Search Index?

Tags: sharepoint, search, wss, sharepoint-search

We need to list documents, list items, etc from a Sharepoint Search Server Express Index by the created date.  The problem is we can't find it in the index even though we've tried to map it to everything we can think of.

[image: SharePoint properties showing created date]

In the Central Admin/Shared Services Administration you will go to the Search Administration page.  I added the metadata properties of most of the date/time fields I could find that  could be the Created Date that I am looking for.  I have tried all the following properties and none of them return the date I am looking for.

[image: All the fields we've tried]

I then “Reset all crawled content” and ran a full crawl.

We are using Search Server Express 2008 and WSS 3.  We call the   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.FullTextSqlQuery to return the data.

We use a query like this:

@"SELECT Title, SiteName, SiteTitle, Write, Path, Filename, ListId, ListItemId,
Created,CreatedBasic14,CreatedBasic16,CreatedBasic4,CreatedDC, CreatedOffice10,    CreatedOffice11,CreatedOffice13,CreatedStartDate,CreatedStartDate1,CreatedPublishedDate,CreatedDateOpened
                            FROM portal..scope()
                            WHERE (CONTAINS (contentclass,'STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'))
                            AND ContentType <> 'Folder'
                            AND (SITE='" + SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "')

My question is what property do I have to set that will allow me to get the correct created date?

Comment: You might try http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I also posted it here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40027/what-field-contains-the-created-date-in-a-sharepoint-search-index

Answer (score 3):

Map "**Created**" to "**Basic:15(Date and Time)**" to get creation date of a list item.

[Answered by Maksymilian Mulawa on sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40027/what-field-contains-the-created-date-in-a-sharepoint-search-index/40106#40106)

Comment: *Comment posted as an answer from user [Fran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5021065/fran):* When you check this property mapping Basic:15 is already present but may be second in order. Move it up as the search returns the first property with a value.